# Middle (vertically) align text inside a <textarea>

Tags: html, css

I have a multi-line search box, and I want everything aligned in the middle. Is it possible to vertically center the content of a `<textarea>`?

Comment: What do you mean "multiline search box"? Could you give us an example?

Comment: `textarea`s are for entering text, it doesn't have any possibility to format it. Can you expand on what you are trying to achieve? There are possibly better solutions.

Comment: yap, back in the days when i was asking this, i tried achieving this with textarea which is really not possible without scripting. The answer was adding HTML5's contenteditable="true" on a table cell with style="vertical-align: middle". If one's project allows modern HTML, this is a rather simple and effective solution.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Back in the days when i was asking this, i tried achieving this with textarea which is really not possible without scripting. The answer was adding HTML5's contenteditable="true" on a table cell with style="vertical-align: middle". If one's project allows modern HTML, this is a rather simple and effective solution.

If instead of adding `<table>` and `<tr>` and `<td>` to your markup, you would like something regular like a `<div>`, you would still need two of them:

```
<div style="display: table">
  <div 
    style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle"
    contenteditable="true">
    I am vertically aligned
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: nowadays I´d use `flex` instead of `table-cell`. So you end up with `<div style="display: flex; align-items: center" contenteditable="true">`

Comment: In Firefox the caret (text-cursor) doesn't respect `text-align: middle` until the user starts typing in the div. Minor but annoying.

Comment: this is really good but is there away we can use events of textarea on div? I have been looking for a better looking textarea, its really good to use a div as textarea with contenteditable but it doesnt have events such as oninput

Answer (score 13):

You can fake the centering with vertical padding.

```css
textarea {
  padding: 30px 0;
}
```

You can also vertically center text by using the `line-height` property, but that does not work with more than one line of text.

Comment: auto is not a valid value for padding

Comment: What would be the magic universal number to use here? Can it be calculated off global font size? FYI, AirBNB (web app) seems to do this in their message reply sticky bottom bar.

Answer (score 9):

There is the HTML5 `contenteditable` attribute.
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_contenteditable.asp

Maybe the `div` tag instead of `textarea` can solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to make a script that determines the elements height, line height, and lines of text and calculate a padding-top, or even \n to prepend the text.

I do not think this is possible with just CSS though.

Comment: You're right, this is not possible with CSS. <textarea> does not recognize the usual fix for this:  display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle;

Answer (score 1):

You cannot vertically center the content of a `<textarea>`. Instead, use a `<div>` with content editing enabled. Then use Flexbox layout to center the text.

```css
[contenteditable] {
  /* Use Flexbox to center the content */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  
  /* Apply min height of 4 lines */
  line-height: 1.2;
  min-height: calc(1.2em * 4);
  
  /* Border styles */
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true">This text is editable.<br>Go ahead and change it.</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution without contenteditable and other heavy stuff (Jquery used for quickness).
The core concept is padding trick (mentioned above) with input event listener that will always scroll to the vertical center of text inside textarea.
**this.scrollHeight - this.offsetHeight** gives the actual height of text block. Scrollbar inside textarea ranges exactly for that height. So by scrolling to 50% of it we have a solution.

```js
$(document).on("input focus", "textarea", function() {
  this.scrollTo(0, (this.scrollHeight - this.offsetHeight) / 2);
});
```

```css
textarea {
  --textarea-height: 6em;
  
  width: 30em;
  height: var(--textarea-height);
  padding: calc(var(--textarea-height) / 2) 0;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

not a solution but a workaround, wrap it in a `label` and set the position of the textarea to the middle. caveat: must recalculate the textarea rows once the text content reaches its limit.

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/syjfoqzx/