# Vertically centered cursor in textarea or editable div

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

Is it possible to put cursor vertically centered in textarea or editable div . See attached image please.

[image]

Comment: not with css only, see the first answer in [this duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677633/middle-vertically-align-text-inside-a-textarea)

Comment: I don't know about the TEXTAREA, but it's certainly possible with a contenteditable DIV...

Comment: You might want to check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677633/middle-vertically-align-text-inside-a-textarea

Comment: @ptriek I think it is related, but not a duplicate because that question only addresses textareas - whereas this one also addresses editable divs.

Comment: I got an idea, give me a sec... (I might be able to make it work with an textarea...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I used a little bit of JavaScript to make it work:

HTML:

```
<div id="test">
    <textarea autofocus></textarea>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#test {
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    line-height: 300px;
}

#test > textarea {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1.4em;
    line-height: 1.4;
    border: none;
    resize: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
ta.onkeyup = function () {
    var n = this.value.match( /\n/g );

    if ( n ) {
        this.style.height = ( n.length + 1 ) * 1.4 + 'em';
    } else {
        this.style.height = '1.4em';
    }
};
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/SPpKY/show/

However, it only works if line-breaks are entered manually...