# centering text inside a textarea while changing the font size

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to fix the text inside the `textarea` when I dynamically change the font size (I want to center the text inside the textrea vertically and horizontally). so I set the  `display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;` but still when change the font size the text position changes.

in lower sizes the text gos up and in huge font sizes the text goes down.

How can I do this?

Here is a prototype:

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  const textarea = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0];
    textarea.style.overflow = "hidden"; 
    textarea.style.userSelect = 'none';
        $('textarea').val("I should be centered");
   $('textarea').css('font-size', 12);
}, 2000);

setTimeout(() => {
        $('textarea').val("I should be centered");
   $('textarea').css('font-size', 52);
}, 4000);

setTimeout(() => {
        $('textarea').val("I should be centered");
   $('textarea').css('font-size', 100);
}, 6000);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<textarea style="font-family: &quot;Open Sans Semibold bold27772842&quot;, sans-serif; font-size: 53.9269px; line-height: normal; font-weight: normal; direction: ltr; text-align: center; color: rgb(230, 224, 236); padding: 5.6373px 9.3955px 0px; height: 81.4775px; transform: translate(0px, 7.02549px); display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;"></textarea>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Middle (vertically) align text inside a <textarea>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677633/middle-vertically-align-text-inside-a-textarea)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using a `div` with [contentEditable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content) instead of a `textarea`?

For instance:

```css
.textarea {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    max-width: 500px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}

.textarea-text {
    max-width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

//meaningless styles

.body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    max-width: 800px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 20px;
}

.textarea-text,
.textarea-text:focus,
.textarea-text:hover {
    outline: unset;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
    <div class="textarea">
        <div class="textarea-text" contentEditable="true">
            hello I'm an editable content.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This solution seems great but when I delete all text content and unfocus using mobile chrome, it won't let me go back to add additional text. Any idea?

Comment: Apparently it is related with finding the right spot of where to place your finger, so min-width for textarea-text, or similar is needed, I guess.

Comment: is there a way to achieve this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73759084/how-grow-a-text-area-height-on-top-when-it-overflows/73759184?noredirect=1#comment130246432_73759184 with this contenteditable div?

Comment: @electronixG just replace `height:200px` with `min-height:200px;`