# HTML/CSS: How to vertically align text in textarea

Tags: html, css

I have the following textarea and CSS:

```css
#map-title {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  flex: 30%;
  height: 100%;
  resize: none;
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="map-title" type="text" name="title" maxlength="50" wrap="hard" cols="25" rows="2">The text-align property has allowed the text to be centred horizontally, but I want it to also be centered vertically so that, regardless of the number of lines of text, the middle line will always be in the middle of the textarea. I suspect I should use padding, but it would need to adjust based on the size and amount of text on the screen, which I'm not sure how to handle (and I would prefer using only CSS if possible).</textarea>
```

The text-align property has allowed the text to be centred horizontally, but I want it to also be centered vertically so that, regardless of the number of lines of text, the middle line will always be in the middle of the textarea. I suspect I should use padding, but it would need to adjust based on the size and amount of text on the screen, which I'm not sure how to handle (and I would prefer using only CSS if possible).

Comment: I made you a snippet. If Angular is important, add the angular tag

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Middle (vertically) align text inside a <textarea>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677633/middle-vertically-align-text-inside-a-textarea)

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/74855402/6934036